# How to flush Asynchronous loggers in Log4J2 (with disruptor)

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, configuration, log4j2

I'm using Log4J2 "Making All Loggers Asynchronous" section by setting:

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector.
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

I process a lot of logs and then stop the appenders before exiting:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger coreLogger = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) logger;
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) coreLogger.getContext();
Map<String, Appender> appenders = context.getConfiguration().getAppenders();
for (Appender appender : appenders.values()) {
  appender.stop();
}
```

By doing so I'm hoping that it will flush the async appender(s) and write to the disk the remaining logs before I exit the program.

But here is what happens:

```
2015-05-19 14:09:58,540 ERROR Attempted to append to non-started appender myFileAppender
Exception in thread "AsyncLogger-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Attempted to append to non-started appender myFileAppender
    at com.lmax.disruptor.FatalExceptionHandler.handleEventException(FatalExceptionHandler.java:45)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Attempted to append to non-started appender myFileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger$PrivateConfig.logEvent(Logger.java:288)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.actualAsyncLog(AsyncLogger.java:305)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent.execute(RingBufferLogEvent.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEventHandler.onEvent(RingBufferLogEventHandler.java:28)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    ... 3 more
```

So the close doesn't look like it's actually flushing and the logger ends up failing.

My conf:

```
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="myFileAppender" fileName="/tmp/test.log" ignoreExceptions="false" immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout><Pattern>%m%n</Pattern></PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%C{1.} %m %level MDC%X%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="myLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="myFileAppender" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="fatal">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

How can I flush / synchronize log4j2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log4j2 has a shutdown hook (for non-web applications) that takes care of waiting for the background thread to process any events still in the queue. So the best thing to do is to not stop the appenders when they are still being used. Let log4j2 take care of the cleanup.

#### Log4j versions earlier than 2.5

To cleanly stop the async logger, you can call `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.stop()`.

#### Log4j 2.5 and later

To cleanly stop the async logger, get a reference to its LoggerContext and stop it:

```java
void stopAsyncLogger() {
    // you might need different arguments to getContext() to find the right one
    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.stop();
}
```

For all versions this blocks until all messages are flushed. Be aware:

- This only works when "Making All Loggers Asynchronous" section by setting:
  `-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector`.
- Are you sure you want to measure this? The disk I/O will dominate your measurements. If you want to include I/O, it may simpler to switch off async logging and measure synchronous logging (which includes the I/O). Most people are interested in the impact of logging on their application, so they only measure how long the calls to the logger take, and don't include the background thread work in their measurements.

Comment: I don't want to stop the JVM though, I just want to flush the messages. I want to compute how much time it took to log the messages for a benchmark so I can't just exit.

Comment: The messages are flushed automatically. Via JMX you can monitor if the  RingBuffer is empty yet.

Comment: If there is no way to do it it's fine but let's be clear about it.

Comment: Thanks, so that looks like what I tried to do when I stop all the appenders of the logger I am using. Would you have an idea of why I get an exception?

Comment: Because of internal dependencies appenders need to be stopped in a precise order.

Comment: OK so I needed to do this:
if (appender instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger) appender.stop();
Marking as solved.

Comment: @RemkoPopma What if one is programmatically creating loggers and appenders? Do they need to call appender.stop() methods for them?

Comment: @gaurav No. Regardless of how appenders and loggers were created, they should not be stopped when they are still being used. The application does not know if Log4j still has work in the queue. Log4j2 has a shutdown hook (for non-web applications) that takes care of waiting for the background thread to process any events still in the queue.  Let log4j2 take care of the cleanup.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Great answer. But, what about the millions of appenders and loggers created programmatically by my application? Is it wise to clear them ? Will they be a memory overhead? Or as you said, should I let log4j2 take care of the cleanup of millions of loggers/appenders?

Comment: This answer is outdated. There is no `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.stop()` method https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncLogger.html

Comment: @RemkoPopma Is there an alternative way to force the flush? (As mentioned in comment above AsyncLogger.stop() does not exists anymore)

Comment: @andresp , the answer is edited with current syntax